# AWS S3 access issue when using qubole/streamx on AWS EMR

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, qubole

I am using qubole/streamx as a kafka sink connector to consume data in kafka and store them in AWS S3. 
I created a user in AIM and permission is `AmazonS3FullAccess`. Then set key ID and key in hdfs-site.xml which dir is assign in `quickstart-s3.properties`.

configuration like below:

**quickstart-s3.properties:**

```
name=s3-sink
connector.class=com.qubole.streamx.s3.S3SinkConnector
format.class=com.qubole.streamx.SourceFormat
tasks.max=1
topics=test
flush.size=3
s3.url=s3://myemrbuckettest/raw_data
hadoop.conf.dir=/data/java/streamx/resource/hadoop-conf
```

**hdfs-site.xml:**

```
<property>
    <name>fs.s3.awsAccessKeyId</name>
    <value>BALABALABALA</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>fs.s3.awsSecretAccessKey</name>
    <value>balabalabala</value>
```

And get this error when use `connect-standalone ./connect-standalone.properties ./quickstart-s3.properties` to start sink connector.

```
[2017-02-14 18:30:32,943] INFO GHFS version: 1.6.0-hadoop2 (com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase:597)
[2017-02-14 18:30:36,406] INFO Couldn't start HdfsSinkConnector: (io.confluent.connect.hdfs.HdfsSinkTask:85)
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: s3n://myemrbuckettest/raw_data
        at io.confluent.connect.hdfs.DataWriter.<init>(DataWriter.java:205)
        at io.confluent.connect.hdfs.HdfsSinkTask.start(HdfsSinkTask.java:77)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.initializeAndStart(WorkerSinkTask.java:221)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:140)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:140)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:175)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: s3n://myemrbuckettest/raw_data
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.processException(Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.java:449)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.processException(Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.java:427)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.handleException(Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.java:411)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.retrieveMetadata(Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.java:181)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:191)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.$Proxy42.retrieveMetadata(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem.getFileStatus(NativeS3FileSystem.java:476)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem.mkdir(NativeS3FileSystem.java:601)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem.mkdirs(NativeS3FileSystem.java:594)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.mkdirs(FileSystem.java:1877)
        at com.qubole.streamx.s3.S3Storage.mkdirs(S3Storage.java:67)
        at io.confluent.connect.hdfs.DataWriter.createDir(DataWriter.java:372)
        at io.confluent.connect.hdfs.DataWriter.<init>(DataWriter.java:173)
        ... 10 more
Caused by: org.jets3t.service.impl.rest.HttpException
        at org.jets3t.service.impl.rest.httpclient.RestStorageService.performRequest(RestStorageService.java:519)
        at org.jets3t.service.impl.rest.httpclient.RestStorageService.performRequest(RestStorageService.java:281)
        at org.jets3t.service.impl.rest.httpclient.RestStorageService.performRestHead(RestStorageService.java:942)
        at org.jets3t.service.impl.rest.httpclient.RestStorageService.getObjectImpl(RestStorageService.java:2148)
        at org.jets3t.service.impl.rest.httpclient.RestStorageService.getObjectDetailsImpl(RestStorageService.java:2075)
        at org.jets3t.service.StorageService.getObjectDetails(StorageService.java:1093)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The region which I used is cn-north-1. Need specify region info in hdfs-site.xml like below, otherwise it will connect to s3.amazonaws.cn as default.

```
<property>
    <name>fs.s3a.access.key</name>
    <value>BALABALABALA</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>fs.s3a.secret.key</name>
    <value>balabalabalabala</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>fs.s3.impl</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem</value>
    <!--value>org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem</value-->
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>fs.s3a.endpoint</name>
    <value>s3.cn-north-1.amazonaws.com.cn</value>connect-standalone ./connect-standalone.properties ./quickstart-s3.properties
  </property>
```